# BigQuery sub query in Join condition

Tags: google-bigquery, subquery, left-join

Hi I am in the process of converting some of TSQL queries to BigQuery Standard SQL and struck at converting JOIN conditions have sub-queries, appreciate if you can provide some help

**TSQL**

```sql
select * From Table1 t1
left join Table3 t2 
  on t2.userid=t1.userid 
    and t2.id in (select min(t3.id) From Table3 t3 where t3.userid=t2.userid and t3.creationdate > t2.creationdate and t3.typeid in (1,3,9))
where t1.creationdate > <date condition>
```

Seems, BigQuery won't directly support sub-queries in WHERE or JOIN conditions. So, is there a way we can achieve same in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do:

```sql
create temp table Table1 AS select 1 userid;
create temp table Table3 AS select 1 userid, 1 id UNION ALL select 1, 2;

select t1.*, Table3.id From Table1 t1
left join 
  (Table3
     join (select min(id) min_id, userid From Table3 t3 group by userid) t3_min_id 
     on Table3.id = t3_min_id.min_id 
       AND Table3.userid = t3_min_id.userid)
on Table3.userid=t1.userid
```

Comment: thanks for quick response Yun. I am wondering is this syntax supports, select * From Table1 t1
left join 
  (Table3 
     join ( Select  ....  I will give a try and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try with:

```
select * From Table1 t1
left join 
  (select * From Table3 t3
     join (select min(id) min_id, userid From Table3 group by userid) t3_min_id 
     on t3.id = t3_min_id.min_id 
       AND t3.userid = t3_min_id.userid) t2
on t2.userid=t1.userid 
where t1.creationdate > Condition
```

I also suggest you to take look in the [BigQuery best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) where is mentioned that is recommended to query only the columns that you need and avoid the use of SELECT *.